# Start message before the method and stop after the message

Tags: jquery

```
function queryDB(callback) {

$.blockUI({css: {
            border: 'none',
            padding: '15px',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
            opacity: .5,
            color: '#fff'
        }});
  var sqlTxt = "SELECT * FROM ITEMS";

  db.transaction(
        function(tx) {

            tx.executeSql(sqlTxt, [],
                    function(tx, results) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                            item_Codes.push({item_code: results.rows.item(i).itemCode, description: results.rows.item(i).description, price: results.rows.item(i).price});
                        }
                        callback(item_Codes);
                    })
                    , errorCB;
        });

  return false;
}
```

I need to start loading message before this methods starts and end of that method i need to stop that.I try above code but it starts with the method instead of before the method

Comment: Okay? Then place the loading message on top of `db.transaction` and remove it on top of `callback(item_Codes)`?

Comment: I did already.See my edit.But  it starts after the method run

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function queryDB(callback) {

    $.blockUI({css: {
                border: 'none',
                padding: '15px',
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                opacity: .5,
                color: '#fff'
            }});

    setTimeout(function(){
        var sqlTxt = "SELECT * FROM ITEMS";

        db.transaction(
            function(tx) {

                tx.executeSql(sqlTxt, [],
                        function(tx, results) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                                item_Codes.push({item_code: results.rows.item(i).itemCode, description: results.rows.item(i).description, price: results.rows.item(i).price});
                            }
                            callback(item_Codes);
                        })
                        , errorCB;
            });
    },0);

    return false;
}
```